# Need to make vbs work on UAC

Tags: windows, vbscript, uac

I am currently trying to automate one of my tasks using vbs, I don't want to use another external program because I want to keep it small and in one place. My vbs script turns on a program with admin privileges and automatically types my password into it. It should but I think vbs, for security reasons, doesn't work with UAC, Please help.
If you need more information please ask.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49333033/edit) and add your code and expalin more your aim

Answer (score 0):

If UAC is enabled on the computer, something like this should work:

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

'Your actual code goes here
```

Comment: This works, thankyou but not in the way i intended. See i want it so that when the .vbs file opens the application in admin mode it is automatically able to select yes or no